# Find K nearest Points to Point P in 2-dimensional plane

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, language-agnostic

***Source: AMAZON INTERVIEW QUESTION***

Given a **point P and other N points** in two dimensional space, find **K points** out of the N points which are **nearest** to P.

What is the most optimal way to do this ?

This [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) page does not provide much of help in building a algorithm.Any ideas/approaches people.

Comment: I balanced you to zero ;) Will follow up with answer

Comment: This is just a variation on the theme "Find the k lowest numbers". Only that you have to calculate the distances for each point.

Comment: @Ingo "calculate the distances for each point" ... that's brute force you are saying ?

Comment: Since Fibonacci Heaps have O(1) insertion and O(log n) deletion shouldn't they admit an O(n + k log n) or O(n + k log k) solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Solution 1** make heap of size K and collect points by minimal distance **O(NLogK)** complexity.

**Solution 2**:
Take and array of size N and Sort by distance. Should be used QuickSort (Hoare modification).
As answer take first K points.
This is too NlogN complexity but it is possible optimize to approximate O(N).
If skip sorting of unnecessary sub arrays. When you split array by 2 sub arrays you should take only array where Kth index located.
complexity will be : N +N/2 +N/4 + ... = **O(N)**.

**Solution 3**: search Kth element in result array and takes all point lesser then founded. Exists **O(N)** alghoritm, similar to search of median.

**Notes**: better use sqr of distance to avoid of sqrt operations, it will be greater faster if point has integer coordinates.

As interview answer better use Solution 2 or 3.

Comment: Can you explain solution 3 a bit more? It seems very similar to solution 2.

Comment: Solution 3 is quickselect algorithm. Store all the distances in an array. Find the index which gives the kth smallest element using method similar to quicksort (Chapter 9 CLRS), then element from index 0 to k-1 will give all the required k points.

Comment: O(N) in solution 2 & 3 is average case complexity. Worst case is still O(NLogK)

Comment: @KunalBalani Wouldn't the worst-case complexity actually be O(NK)? (In the case where the window size is reduced by only 1 with each round of quickselect partitioning, e.g., if the array is already sorted and you keep choosing the last element as the pivot)

Comment: How can one find array(s) that must be skipped out prior to sorting!?

Comment: Solution #2 is known as `Quickselect` , and could perhaps be also considered a combination of #3 as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Answer (score 8):

For just a single query...

Maintain a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) of size `k`.

For each point, calculate the distance to the point `P`. Insert that distance into the heap and delete the maximum from the heap if the size of the heap is greater than `k`.

Running time: `O(n log k)`

Answer (score 5):

Solution 1

```
private List<Point> nearestKPoint_1(List<Point> list, final Point center, int k) {
    List<Point> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    PriorityQueue<Point> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(k + 1, new Comparator<Point>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
            return distance(center, o2) - distance(center, o1);
        }
    });
    for (Point p : list) {
        maxHeap.offer(p);
        if (maxHeap.size() > k) {
            maxHeap.poll();
        }
    }
    Iterator<Point> i = maxHeap.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ans.add(i.next());
    }
    return ans;
}

public int distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y);
}

static class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Point point = (Point) o;

        if (x != point.x) return false;
        return y == point.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Solution 2

```
private List<Point> nearestKPoint_2(List<Point> list, final Point center, int k) {
    List<Point> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    Distance[] nums = new Distance[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = new Distance(distance(center, list.get(i)), i);
    }
    quickSelect(nums, k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        ans.add(list.get(nums[i].i));
    }
    return ans;
}

private void quickSelect(Distance[] nums, int k) {
    int start = 0, end = nums.length - 1;
    while (start < end) {
        int p = partition(nums, start, end);
        if (p == k) {
            return;
        } else if (p < k) {
            start = p + 1;
        } else {
            end = p - 1;
        }
    }
}
private int partition(Distance[] nums, int start, int end) {
    Distance pivot = nums[start];
    int i = start, j = end + 1;
    while (true) {
        while (i < end && nums[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
        while (j > start && nums[--j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);
        if (i >= j) {
            break;
        }
        swap(nums, i, j);
    }
    swap(nums, start, j);
    return j;
}

private void swap(Distance[] nums, int i, int j) {
    Distance tmp = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = tmp;
}

class Distance implements Comparable<Distance> {
    int d;
    int i;

    public Distance(int d, int i) {
        this.d = d;
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Distance o) {
        return this.d - o.d;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the code be different if the input was not a convenient Point type, but rather a matrix of points such as [[3,4],[1,2],[5,3]]? I literally can't find anything on accessing the x y values directly in this case.

Comment: Just to mention that the comparator, could be defined like the following :

```java
PriorityQueue<Point> maxHeap =  new PriorityQueue<Point>((a, b) -> distance(a, center) - distance(b, center));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use KD tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree to partition space and given the point you will be able to gradually search for neighbors using binary search.
Benefit of using this approach is that it easily scales up to online version when you receive points/queries in runtime one by one or in batches.

Answer (score 0):

```
// point_type pt, length_sq(p) { return pt[0] * pt[0] + pt[1] * pt[1]}
// std::vector<point_type> points to search.
// The algorithm should recursion depth to 
//       O(k * log(points.size())), and
// running time to O(points.size()).

std::nth_element(
               points.begin(),
               points.begin() + k,
               points.end(),
               [&pt](point_type const & a)
               {
                    return length_squared(a - pt);
               });

// points[0], ... , points[k - 1] are the closest points to pt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
   public int[][] kClosest(int[][] points, int K) {
        double [] combinationArr = new double[points.length];
        Hashtable<Double,int[]> pt = new Hashtable();
        for (int i = 0; i <points.length; i++) {
            int [] in = points[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < in.length - 1; j++) {
                Integer x = in[j];
                Integer y = in[j + 1];

                double powerX=Math.pow(x, 2);
                double powerY = Math.pow(y, 2);
                double combination= (Double)(Math.sqrt(powerX + powerY));
                pt.put(combination, points[i]);
                combinationArr[i] = combination;
            }

        }

        Arrays.sort(combinationArr);
        int [][] kpoints = new int[K][K];
        for (int n = 0; n < K; n++) {
            kpoints[n] = pt.get(combinationArr[n]);
        }
       return kpoints;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# Solution using LINQ

```
public int[][] KClosest(int[][] points, int[][] p, int K) {

    var orderedPoints = points.OrderBy(point => Math.Pow(point[0]-p[0], 2) + Math.Pow(point[1]-p[1], 2));
    return orderedPoints.Take(K).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This solution is to find the closest points to the origin not to a different point P.

Comment: @elulcao thanks for the catch, it was an easy fix.

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with below approach ?

1) Calculate distance from given point to other points.

2) Store the distance and index of that point to `TreeMap<Double,Integer> map`

3) Select top K elements from map. It's values will give index of Point element from points array.

The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time,

Comment: It would be great to have the running time of your algorithm. (1) is O(n). (2) depends on the implementation of TreeMap, if it is the Java TreeMap, it guarantees log N for put and get, and maintains sorted order of elements. Thus, (2) is O(n log n) and (3) is O(k log n). Total running time is O((n + k) log n).

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void NearestPoints() {
    int[][] Points = { new int[] { -16, 5 },
                       new int[] { -1, 2 },
                       new int[] { 4, 3 },
                       new int[] { 10, -2 },
                       new int[] { 0, 3 },
                       new int[] {- 5, -9 } };
    // Linq Order by default use quick sort which will be best suited in this.
    var orderPoint = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Points.Length)
                     orderby Math.Sqrt( Points[i][0] * Points[i][0] 
                                         + Points[i][1] * Points[i][1] )
                     select new int[][] { Points[i] };
    var result = orderPoint.Take(3);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is asking for the general solution, not a specific code snippet to solve a single instance of the problem.